# "I can't load ApplicationContext"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, jhipster

I'm trying to run a junit test in my app. this project was create with Jhipster and is Spring 1.4. The app work fine in normal dev context but when I try to run in test mode it doesnt.

-- application-dev.yml--

```
spring:
profiles:
    active: dev
    include: swagger
devtools:
    restart:
        enabled: true
    livereload:
        enabled: false 
jackson:
    serialization.indent_output: true
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/easyschedule?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
    username: root
    password: *
    hikari:
        data-source-properties:
            cachePrepStmts: true
            prepStmtCacheSize: 250
            prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
            useServerPrepStmts: true
jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    database: MYSQL
    show-sql: true
    properties:
        hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: true
mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: mymail@gmail.com username.
    password: * 
    protocol: smtp
    tls: true
    properties.mail.smtp:
        auth: true
        starttls.enable: true
        ssl.trust: smtp.gmail.com
messages:
    cache-seconds: 1
thymeleaf:
    cache: false
liquibase:
contexts: dev
server:
port: 8080
jhipster:
http:
    version: V_1_1 # To use HTTP/2 you will need SSL support (see above the "server.ssl" configuration)
security:
    remember-me:
        key: *******
mail: 
    from: mymail@gmail.com  
    base-url: http://127.0.0.1:8080
metrics: 
    jmx.enabled: true
    graphite: 
        enabled: false
        host: localhost
        port: 2003
        prefix: easyschedule
logging:
    logstash: 
        enabled: false
        host: localhost
        port: 5000
        queue-size: 512
```

--Application.yml test--

```
spring:
application:
    name: easyschedule
jackson:
    serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps: false
cache:
    type: none
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:easyschedule;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    name:
    username:
    password:
jpa:
    database-platform: io.github.jhipster.domain.util.FixedH2Dialect
    database: H2
    open-in-view: false
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
        naming:
            physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
            implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
    properties:
        hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: true
        hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: validate
mail:
    host: localhost
messages:
    basename: i18n/messages
mvc:
    favicon:
        enabled: false
thymeleaf:
    mode: XHTML
liquibase:
contexts: test
security:
basic:
    enabled: false
server:
port: 10344
address: localhost
jhipster:
async:
    core-pool-size: 2
    max-pool-size: 50
    queue-capacity: 10000
security:
```

---

Edited error trace. when I try to run in test mode it doesnt.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
... 24 more


    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:967)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [fecha_seleccion] in table [asignatura_profesor]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:136)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:191)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
```

[image]

I had modified the post cleaning of code and images

Comment: Can you please post the complete exception stacktrace?

Comment: I edited stracktrace in the post. thanks.

Comment: @Kara can you also post `EasyscheduleApp` class. Just to make sure it is loading all the configurations

Comment: Please check missing column [fecha_seleccion] in table [asignatura_profesor].

Comment: @abosancic I have checked column fecha_seleccion in table asignatura_profesor and I found it. I have post screenshot about that.

Comment: @ sairamch04 I post screenshot with EasyscheduleApp class

Comment: @Kara you have posted screenshot of mysql database table but you executing junit test with H2 in memory database. Actually your junit context cannot be created and not configured proper.

Comment: @abosancic then have I to create test for all entitys that I use in profesor entity? because profesor has a relationsip n:m(asgnatura_profesor table/entity) with asignatura  and I dont have test for asgnatura_profesor entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I had forgotten to post the solution to this problem. I know that is really latter but maybe to someone can to util.

You sould modified in application.yml [test] :

```
jpa:
    database-platform: io.github.jhipster.domain.util.FixedH2Dialect
    database: H2
    open-in-view: false
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
        naming:
            physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
            implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
    properties:
        hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: true
        **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: create.**
```

notice that on the line:
**hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: create.**
it sould be like Create.